# Docker syslog driver not delevering to remote syslog-server

Tags: logging, docker, syslog

The goal is to send logs from docker containers to an existing centralized remote syslog server. The remote syslog server is hooked up with an elk stack (Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana) from where log messages can be browsed.

The containers are started with (this is an example)

```
$ docker run  --rm --log-driver=syslog 
  --log-opt syslog-address=udp://123.1.2.34:514 
  --log-opt tag="docker-container"
  --log-opt syslog-facility=user 
  ubuntu echo "this message never appears in the remote syslog"
```

**Nothing appears in the remote syslog!**

However it is possible to deliver messages via the utility logger

```
$ logger -i --udp 
 --tag testtag --server 123.1.2.34 
 --port 514 this message is received and appears :)
```

Using wireshark we were able to extract the raw syslog messages:

Logger Syslog message - OK

```
"USER.NOTICE: 1 2016-01-07T10:47:19.115387+01:00 Ikaros testtag 10354 - [timeQuality tzKnown="1" isSynced="0"] this message is received and appears :)"
```

Docker log_driver=syslog message - Fails

```
"USER.INFO: 2016-01-07T11:25:57+01:00 Ikaros docker/docker-containe[823]: this message never appears in the remote syslog\n"
```

The only difference seems to be the **number** "1" before the timestamp, the **timestamp format** and the **timeQuality** parameter.

Dockers logging documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/logging/overview/ doesn't mention these parameters. Is it possible to configure the docker syslog format to match the one created from the utility logger?